# Handle methods differently in Vue depending on mobile or not

Tags: vue.js

I'm having trouble setting up my Vue components to handle their methods differently if the user is on mobile. For instance a navigation drop down, if a user clicks on a link, I want to prevent them from going to that location, but instead drop down the drop down. Whereas on desktop, I want them to go to it if they click on it and only drop down on hover. I'll need this for so many other aspects of my project.

I have a main Vue instance:

```
var Main = new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    data: {
        mobile: true
    },

    ready: function() {
        if( document.clientWidth >= 992 )
        {
            this.mobile = false;
        }
    }
});

export default Main;
```

Then for my components, I'm doing something like this:

```
import Main from './../Main';

var NavLink = Vue.component('navlink', {
    template: '#nav-link-template',

    replace: true,

    data: function() {
        return {
        }
    },

    props: ['text', 'url'],

    ready: function() {
    },

    methods: {
        handleClick: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(Main.mobile);

            if( Main.mobile )
            {
                if( this.$children.length )
                {
                    // Has dropdown
                    this.$children[0].dropDown();
                }
                else
                {
                    // No dropdown so redirect user
                    window.location = this.url;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Not mobile so let user go
                window.location = this.url;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Not only does `Main.mobile` return the default value no matter what resolution because their ready methods seem to run BEFORE the Main ready method.. but this also feels like the wrong setup.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Use mixins https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

First, according to you code, you dont need Main commonjs module to be a vuejs instance. Make it as a simple js object

```
Main = {
    mobule: document.clientWidth >= 992
}

export default Main;
```

Or you may want to handle client window size dynamically

```
var Main = new Vue({
    created: function() {
        // dunno why v-on="resize: func" not working
        global.window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            //calc width and heigh somehow
            self.$broadcast('resize', width, heigh);
        });
    }
});

export default Main;
```